# Passing defined type in main to header in C

Tags: c, header, typedef

So, as the title says, I am supposed to define a type in main file and, somehow, pass it to header. I tried to do that in any way, but I am out of ideas.

I define it like this: "typedef int DATA;" and use it in header as a data type.

I tried inserting typedef before including header but still it isnt recognised.

Any ideas? Or it is not even possible to do it in this way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int DATA;

#include "PriorityQueue.h"

int main(){
    int priority;
    DATA value;
```

That's beginning of my main

```
#ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE_H_
#define PRIORITY_QUEUE_H_

struct priorityQueue{
    int priority;
    DATA value;
    struct priorityQueue *next;
};
typedef struct priorityQueue LINK;

void createEmpty(LINK **head);
void add(LINK **head, int p, DATA v);
void deleteElement(LINK **head, int *p, DATA *v);
//void print(LINK *head);
void checkIfEmpty(LINK *head);
void destroy(LINK *head);
#endif
```

Header

```
||=== Build: Release in PriorityQueue (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.h|6|error: unknown type name 'DATA'|
~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.h|11|error: unknown type name 'DATA'| 
~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.h|12|error: unknown type name 'DATA'| 
~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.c|10|error: unknown type name 'DATA'| 
~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.c|44|error: unknown type name 'DATA'| 
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
 Used ~ instead of my destination
```

Comment: Show minimal example code of the problem. Most likely your typedef should be in the header, but it is a little unclear what you are doing.

Comment: @user694733 I've added a bit of my program, but, as I compile it as project, it gives me an error: error: unknown type name 'DATA'.
I use codeblocks to make a project.

Comment: Where are `add` and `deleteElement` functions defined? If they are not in same file as main, then `DATA` won't be available there, and will probably throw a compilation error. It might help if you added *complete* compiler error messages you get.

Comment: @user694733 I get the same errors in the lines where DATA is in header and in other file where are my functions defined, no other kind of errors.

Comment: Please post the **complete** error message.

Comment: ||=== Build: Release in PriorityQueue (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.h|6|error: unknown type name 'DATA'|

~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.h|11|error: unknown type name 'DATA'|

~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.h|12|error: unknown type name 'DATA'|

~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.c|10|error: unknown type name 'DATA'|

~\PriorityQueue\PriorityQueue.c|44|error: unknown type name 'DATA'|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
Used ~ instead of my destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `typedef int DATA;` in PriorityQueue.h before `struct priorityQueue`, and make sure PriorityQueue.h is included in PriorityQueue.c.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you shouldn't do that but assuming you have a good reason to do it, it works if you put the typedef before the inclusion. I don't know how do you tested it but this works ok for me.

$ cat header.h

```
typedef struct 
{
  MYDATA a;
  MYDATA b;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

$ cat main.c

```
typedef int MYDATA;
#include "header.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 
 MYSTRUCT s = {0, 1};
 s.a = 1;
 s.b++;

 return 0;
}
```

It compiles without warning and executing it with gdb I see the types properly defined.

Comment: hmm, yours works for me too, but mine doesn't. I'll add my program

Comment: Yours work for me too. I completed the main with `value = 1` and `value++` to see if it does something. It compiles with a warning about `priority` being unused and runs properly.
What specific error are you getting?

Comment: error: unknown type name 'DATA'.
As I launch my program separately, it works normally. But when I try doing a project(using Codeblocks) it gives me this.