# C Unknown type name 'DATA'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks, typedef

I don't really understand why I've been getting this error : Unknown type name 'DATA'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int DATA;
#include "PriorityQueue.h"


int main(){
    int priority;
    DATA value;
    LINK *head;
    createEmpty(&head);
    add(&head, 1, 7);
    checkIfEmpty(head);
    add(&head, 5, 5);
    add(&head, 3, 4);
    deleteElement(&head, &priority, &value);
    add(&head, 1, 3);
    destroy(head);
    createEmpty(&head);
    add(&head, 10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "PriorityQueue.h"

void add(LINK **head, int p, DATA v){
    LINK *curr=(*head);
    LINK *beforeCurr=(*head);
    LINK *newElement=NULL;
    if((*head)->priority==-1){
        (*head)->priority=p;
        (*head)->value=v;
    }

    else{
        newElement=(LINK*)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
        newElement->priority=p;
        newElement->value=v;
        newElement->next=NULL;

        while(p>(curr->priority) && curr->next!=NULL){
            beforeCurr=curr;
            curr=curr->next;
        }

        if(curr->next==NULL && p>(curr->priority))
            curr->next=newElement;

        else if(curr==(*head)){
            newElement->next=curr;
            (*head)=newElement;
        }
        else{
            beforeCurr->next=newElement;
            newElement->next=curr;
        }
    }
}

void deleteElement(LINK **head, int *p, DATA *v){
    LINK *curr=(*head);
    LINK *currB=(*head);
    while(curr->next!=NULL) {
        currB=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    currB->next=NULL;
    (*p)=curr->priority;
    (*v)=curr->value;
    free(curr);
}

void checkIfEmpty(LINK *head){
    if(head->priority==-1)
    printf("Queue is empty\n\n");
    else
    printf("Queue is not empty\n\n");
}

void destroy(LINK *head) {
    LINK *current;
    LINK *next;
    current=head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        next=current->next;
        free(current);
        current=next;
    }
    head=NULL;
}


void createEmpty(LINK **head) {
    LINK *curr=NULL;
    curr=(LINK*)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
    curr->next = NULL;
    curr->priority = -1;
    (*head)=curr;
}
```

Functions file

```
#ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE_H_
#define PRIORITY_QUEUE_H_

typedef struct priorityQueue{
    int priority;
    DATA value;
    struct priorityQueue *next;
}LINK;

void createEmpty(LINK **head);
void add(LINK **head, int p, DATA v);
void deleteElement(LINK **head, int *p, DATA *v);
void checkIfEmpty(LINK *head);
void destroy(LINK *head);
#endif
```

Header

I use a project on codeblocks to compile it. 
Also, "typedef int DATA;" on main would be preferred

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing defined type in main to header in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811140/passing-defined-type-in-main-to-header-in-c)

Comment: This is duplicate of your earlier post.Please don't double post. Delete this, and edit your old post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare `typedef int DATA;` in a header file and include that header file in all your source files.

Currently there is no way for other source files to know what `DATA` is.

Comment: Isn't there any way of keeping it in main?

Comment: No,there is no way to do so unless you declare `typedef int DATA;` in all source files,which same as including a header.

Answer (score 1):

The `typedef` keyword obeys scoping rules, as explained here: 
[Are typedef and #define the same in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c)

This means that if you declare:

```
typedef int DATA;
```

And this line isn't included in another file it wont be declared there.

`DATA` should be declared in every file that uses it either by including another file which declared it or by explicitly declaring it.